# Values get rearranged by JSONObject constructor

Tags: android, json

I have this:

```
String foo = 

    "options": {
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6",
      "7",
      "8",
      "9",
    }
```

But the `JSONObject` constructor rearranges the keys:

```
new JSONObject(foo).toString() = 

    "options": {
      "6",
      "3",
      "7",
      "2",
      "5",
      "1",
      "4",
      "8",
      "9",
    }
```

The new order is reproducible, meaning each execution results in the same (seemingly random) rearrangement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not look like valid JSON to me.  First, there is not `{}` or `[]` surrounding the entire string.  Second, it looks like the data associated with `options` should be inside and array (`[]`) not be an object(`{}`). If it was an array, the order would be preserved, whereas with the values just being declared as properties, there is no guarantee on their order.

Comment: Yeah, forgive my syntax.  I just pseudo-grabbed a piece of my JSONArray for the sake of an example.  I will try making it an array and see if that preserves order.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In json sequence of the fields is not important, only their nesting.

Comment: I see.  So there is no way to preserve sequence in JSON?

Comment: No.JSON Format does not support the sequence of fields

Answer (score 1):

Your example `Strings` are invalid JSON. You have a bare top-level field `options`, and no values for it's fields.

A javascript *object*, it's JSON representation, and in particular a `JSONObject`, do not guarantee an ordering of the fields.

From the [JSONObject javadoc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html):

> A JSONObject is an unordered collection of name/value pairs.

You *can* maintain an ordering by using an array. So if your data is or can be represented as an array - from your example it *looks* like an array - then the order of the elements *will* be maintained.